# Google Chart in object have wrong context

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm trying to make a js object to draw google line chart. My problem is that callback in `google.charts.load` have different context because of which I can not use property `this._data`

```
MyNewObject = SomeOldObject.extend({
    initialize: function (data, options) {
        this._data = data;
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ["line", "corechart"]
            , "callback": this.loadData
            //, "context": this //This doesn't do anything
        });
    }
    , loadData: function () {
        this._dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        // here I'd like to add data from this._data to this._dataTable but context is different
    }
})
```

How can I pass context in `google.charts.load` callback call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that WhiteHat deleted his answer, it helped me to realize solution:

```
MyNewObject = SomeOldObject.extend({
    initialize: function (data, options) {
        this._data = data;
        var context = this;
        var callback = function () {
            context.loadData(context);
        };
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ["line", "corechart"]
            , "callback": callback
        });
    }
    ,
    loadData: function (context) {
        this._dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        //now I can use context._data
    }
})
```